# Wordpress code injection in header

Tags: wordpress

I'm having problems with a Wordpress installation I currently have.

There has been a large amount of code being injected into the header and I'm not sure where its coming from. I've looked over all the files in the wp-content folder and nothing has been found.

I've pasted the source here: http://pastebin.com/cLS6s9V8. It starts at line 96.

This is happening with all the pages. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Any plugins that might be causing it? Have you checked your site with Sucuri to make sure it hasn't been hacked?

Comment: I have deactivated all my plugins. Will check with Sucuri now.

Comment: @JimmyPena this is what I get http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/jeansymolanza.com/shift-uk-new/

Comment: Sorry @JimmyPena! Forgot to add the link I've updated the comment

Comment: Does this help? http://wordpress.org/support/topic/un-necessary-care2com-links-in-my-source-file

Comment: I can't find anything like that in the functions.php file

Comment: There are numerous possible fixes in that post. Did you try them all?

Comment: Yes. None of them are working unfortunately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the location, I would say something hooked into the wp_head() call of your wordpress site. Maybe a rogue plugin?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head

Comment: All plugins have been deactivated.

Comment: This is what I get from Sucuri: http://labs.sucuri.net/db/malware/malware-entry-mwspamseo